# star unpacking for own classes

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I was wondering if it's possible to use star unpacking with own classes rather than just builtins like `list` and `tuple`.

```
class Agent(object):
    def __init__(self, cards):
        self.cards = cards
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.cards)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.cards
```

And be able to write

```
agent = Agent([1,2,3,4])
myfunc(*agent)
```

But I get:

```
TypeError: visualize() argument after * must be a sequence, not Agent
```

Which methods do I have to implement in order to make unpacking possible?

Comment: Your `__iter__` should return an iterator over your cards, not the length of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make class iterable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/how-to-make-class-iterable)

Comment: @Rogalski I disagree this is a duplicate, it's non-obvious that making it iterable solves the star-unpacking issue (though it does).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exception message:

> argument after * must be a sequence

should really say, `argument after * must be an iterable`.

Often star-unpacking is called **"iterable unpacking"** for this reason. *See [PEP 448 (Additional Unpacking Generalizations)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) and [PEP 3132 (Extended Iterable Unpacking)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).*

*Edit: Looks like this has been [fixed for python 3.5.2 and 3.6](https://bugs.python.org/issue4806). In future it will say:*

> argument after * must be an iterable

---

In order to have star unpack, your class must be an iterable i.e. it must define an `__iter__` that returns an iterator:

```
class Agent(object):
    def __init__(self, cards):
        self.cards = cards
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.cards)
    def __iter__(self):
        return (card for card in self.cards)
```

then:

```
In [11]: a = Agent([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [12]: print(*a)  # Note: in python 2 this will print the tuple
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: This bug was fixed in January! https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1123d9a07b4ab916e4d800308053980bcf8dbd57/Python/ceval.c#L5038-L5039