# Unpacking a class

Tags: python, argument-unpacking

I'd like to make a class that unpacks it's objects like a dictionary.

For example, with a dictionary you can do this

```
foo = {
  "a" : 1
  "b" : 2
}

def bar(a,b):
   return a + b

bar(**foo)
```

outputs `3`

And I'd like to be able to do this

```
class FooClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

f = FooClass()
bar(**f)
```

and have it output `3`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837520/implement-packing-unpacking-in-an-object) is the most related question I could find but it doesn't address this so I'm thinking it might not be possible.

---

Currently what my solution would be this:

```
class FooClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
          "a" : self.a,
          "b" : self.b
        }
```

```
f = FooClass()
bar(**f.to_dict())
```

Comment: That's not really possible as far as I'm aware, unless you're actually subclassing a `Mapping`. Otherwise it'll be something like `**vars(f)` or `**f.__dict__`  or `**f.as_dict()`.

Comment: @deceze I'll look into subclassing mapping, thanks!

Comment: @deceze is the recommended answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict) post what you'd recommend?"

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601268/class-that-acts-as-mapping-for-unpacking and https://stackoverflow.com/q/37400133/4046632

Comment: @buran the second link might, the first is linked in my question. So does ** call the `keys` function behind the scene?

Comment: All of the links, incl. the one you post suggest that you implement `__iter__` for your class. In this `__iter__` dunder you can return whatever you want

Comment: There's a function `vars` Python, which returns the dict attributes of python.

Then your case can be done with:

```bar(**vars(FooClass()))```

Comment: you might be looking for `dataclasses.astuple`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, writing a conformant subclass of the [`collections.abc.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping) abstract class is the way to go. To (concretely) subclass this class, you need to implement `__getitem__`, `__len__`, and `__iter__` to behave consistently like a dictionary would. So that means `__getitem__` expects a string, `__iter__` returns an iterable of strings, etc.

For a simple example, we'll simply delegate all of these to `self.__dict__`, but in real code you'd likely want to do something more refined.

```
from collections.abc import Mapping

class FooClass(Mapping):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __getitem__(self, x):
        return self.__dict__[x]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__dict__)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__dict__)

def bar(a, b):
    return a + b

foo = FooClass(40, 2)
print(bar(**foo))
```

Comment: Actually, only `__iter__` is needed in this case

Comment: Do you have a documentation link where that's specified? All I could find was "`**kwargs` expects a dictionary", which is obviously an oversimplification since the above code works. So I wasn't sure exactly where the line is drawn.

Comment: @Drecker I get `Can't instantiate abstract class _____ with abstract methods <names of methods>` when I don't include the three methods @Silvio specifies

Comment: @Drecker Or are you saying that you don't need to subclass mapping either?

Comment: Yeah if I don't subclass `Mapping`, then I get `TypeError: bar() argument after ** must be a mapping, not FooClass` (even with all of the same code from above, just w/o the superclass). I think you *have* to be a `Mapping`. But I'd love to know where that's specified in the Python docs.

Comment: My bad, apparently implementing just `__iter__` is not enough (I just tested it)

Answer (score 2):

Aside from reyling on `vars(f)` or `f.__dict__`, you could use a dataclass.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class FooClass:
    a: int
    b: int
```

Demo:

```
>>> f = FooClass(1, 2)
>>> asdict(f)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: There are so many goodies in the `dataclasses` module. Someday I need to just read it start to finish. I had no idea `asdict` was a thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
def bar(a, b):
   return a + b
  
class FooClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

f = FooClass(1, 2)

print(bar(*f.__dict__.values()))

# print(bar(**f.__dict__)) # Also works
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: or alternatively ```**f.__dict__```